# Why $i^2=-1$ in complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

Why do we use specifically iota (where $i^2=-1$) in complex numbers? Complex numbers are used in multi-dimensional applications. But we can also use any symbolic term in place of $i$. Why do we use specifically iota? What is the link between the equation $i^2=-1$ and Argand diagram?

Comment: You can use whatever symbol you want for whatever you want, as long as you're clear about it. Engineers often use $j$ instead of $i$. My guess is that $i$ is often reserved for electric current in those contexts.

Comment: are you asking why we commonly denote the standard basis by $\{1, i\}$? or why we use that specific basis?

Comment: I am asking if `i` (iota) has to originate from the above mentioned equation or it is just convention?

Comment: Why do we use $\in$ (epsilon) in sets? Why do we use $\pi$,$e$ for an irrational number.? Why does nodding your head mean yes? Because we, humans have defined it.!

Comment: As far as Argand diagram is concerned, it was discovered by someone named Argand! We couldn't have represented complex numbers on the normal coordinate plane, so...

Comment: The *i* is **not** a iota. Iotas do not have dots.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it is $i$ for *imaginary*, that is what I was always told.